# Requesting permissions in Android 6.0 (API level 23)

Tags: android

Is it necessary that requesting each dangerous permission it needs while the app is running Android 6.0 or higher?I have requested the following dangerous permissions,but there are only four dialogs.

The premissions

```
 public static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[]{
        android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,
        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS,
        android.Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS,
        android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA
};
```

The dialogs

1.Allow the app to make and manage phone calls?

2.Allow the app to access photos,media,and files on your device?

3.Allow the app to access this device's location?

4.Allow the app to access your contacts?

I cant get the permissions such as         android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS,
        android.Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS,
        android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA,neither code nor system setting.

Comment: Aren't all the permissions supposed to be mentioned in the Android manifest?

Comment: are there any errors?

Comment: @Motee you are seeing only 4 dialog because there is a concept of permission group for example READ and WRITE permission can be clubbed into one group.

Comment: It's running smoothly in my phone Android 6.0

Comment: @dex It's true ,but there is no CAMERA  requesting dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Special Permissions**

> There are a couple of permissions that don't behave like normal and
>   dangerous permissions. WRITE_SETTINGS is
>   particularly sensitive, so most apps should not use them. If an app
>   needs one of these permissions, it must declare the permission in the
>   manifest, and send an intent requesting the user's authorization. The
>   system responds to the intent by showing a detailed management screen
>   to the user.

**Demo**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Context context;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodName);
        textView.setText(getResources().getText(R.string.txt_name));
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                boolean result = true;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    result = Settings.System.canWrite(context);
                    Log.d("TAG", "Can Write Settings: " + result);
                    if (result) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Write allowed :-)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Write not allowed :-(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It's a good idea to deal with the permission WRITE_SETTINGS.But I'm still in doubt, that should I request the permission CAMERA  in just the same way？

Comment: you should request camera permission as traditional way its not sensitive? And if my answer help you in anyway then you can tick mark and vote up thanks happy coding :)